# ASIHTTPRequest sdk 5.1

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I recently updated xcode and as a result began getting the following error when compiling code which uses ASIHTTPRequest:

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIHTTPRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TargetAddressCaptureViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have already tried linking: libz.dylib, libz.1.1.3.dylib, libz.1.2.5.dylib

Any suggestions?

Comment: iPhone code or Mac OS x86 code?

Comment: did you use a static Library or do you just include the files?

Comment: As a side note, the developer of ASIHTTPRequest is no longer maintaining that project.

Comment: I'd migrate to [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

Comment: I am using the iPhone code and I just includes the files.

Answer (score 6):

Check if "ASIHTTPRequest.m" being build under your Project > Target > Build Phases > Compile Sources.
I once had the same issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

also `ASIHTTPRequest` won't work with ARC.

Make sure you switch off the ARC using **-fno-objc-arc** in Project > Target > Build Phases > Compile Sources